# How to check if Tree was hit or not in libgdx scene2d?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

Basically all I want is to clear selection of the tree if user clicked not on the tree. My current code is:

```
    entityTree.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            if (entityTree.getNodeAt(y) == null) {
                entityTree.getSelection().clear();
            }
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't work for two reasons:

1. `clicked` is only called if the tree is actually clicked. If click happens on some button or wherever else, the tree doesn't get a click event.
2. Current code checks only y-component. It should be combined with code that checks if tree boundaries are hit.

Comment: did you set the bounds of the entityTree? If you didn't it cant know how big it is so there wont be any event on it.

Comment: Well I tried setBounds() but it didn't work. I guess it's because the tree is in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    tree.getStage().addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            if (tree.getStage().hit(x, y, true) != tree || tree.getNodeAt(y) == null)
                tree.getSelection().clear();
            return false;
        }
    });
```